# DAX: Distinct Count of Patients where sum of column equals value

Tags: powerbi, ssas, dax

I have this data:

[image]

I'd like to get a count of distinct patients who have no occurrences of Event Y after their Event X.  In other words, I'm interested in knowing the distinct count of patients whose sum of all Event Ys is equal to 1. I tried the following (table name = Basic):

CALCULATE( DISTINCTCOUNT( Basic[Patient] ),
    FILTER( Basic, Sum( Basic[Event Y] ) = 1 ))

This does not work and I'm not sure why.  Ultimately need to get to a metric that says X% of total patients have no Event Y after Event X (50% with this tiny data set).

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Hi I am not sure why you want to sum in filter  use following might resolve your first step  MyCount = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Sample'[Patient]),FILTER(All('Sample'),'Sample'[Event Y]=1))

Comment: Thanks @RajatJaiswal for your response.  The DAX formula you gave did not get me to the answer though.  It returns a total count of 2, but the count for this data should be 1.  I was using 'SUM' because I am completely new to DAX and don't really know what I'm doing, and 2 because it is the sum of each patient events Y that should be equal to 1.  That's what I'm trying to identify.

Comment: Hi @Troy, if I understand your problem correctly. you want patient count who has event x value 1 then event Y value 1 in a row. is that correct?

Comment: Ultimately what I need is a distinct count of patients who have no event Y **after**  their event X.  So it's not patient count where event x = 1 & event Y = 1.  Every patient will have that.  It's patient count where the sum of all Event Ys is equal to 1.  Note this is the case for Patient YY but not for Patient ZZ so the result of the measure should be 1.